# Oracle SQL - What is faster than 3 "and exists()" in the where space?

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, exists

Is there a better way to write

```
Select distinct id_no
from revenue_table
where (exists (select * from revenue_table i 
       where revenue_type = 'Shipping' and i.id_no = r.id_no)
  and exists(select * from revenue_table i 
       where revenue_type = 'Reproduction' and i.id_no = r.id_no)
  and exists(select * from revenue_table i 
       where revenue_type = 'Tape' and i.id_no = r.id_no))
```

id_no represents a form, which is entered into the table once for each revenue item on the form.  Same revenue_type's can appear multiple times.  There are many advanced functions that work using OR logic but I cannot seem to find any functions using AND set theory.  It would be really nice if GROUP BY had some function to compare a group such as id_no to a set like (Shipping, Reproduction, Tape)

Does this exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be

```
SELECT id_no
FROM   revenue_table
WHERE  revenue_type IN ( 'Tape', 'Shipping', 'Reproduction' )
GROUP  BY id_no
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT revenue_type) = 3
```

You'll have to test whether or not it is an improvement.

Comment: +1 : Single scan of the table, not gonna beat that as far as I can tell.

Comment: I ran some tests and I believe this appears faster in run time by about 20% on the large table it is going over.  I have never thought to use a "count(distinct)" statement before.  Thank you

Comment: @Matt - Do you have an index on `(id_no, revenue_type)`?

Comment: @Matt - That will make a significant difference.

Comment: @wildplasser - No it doesn't. It counts `distinct revenue_type` so all three have to be present. If there is a unique constraint on `id_n,revenue_type` it could just use `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Well, there could be two 'Shipping' entries and one 'Tape' or 'Reproduction', and they will be counted as three. Duh, now I see it's count distinct ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A number of relational operators imply logical AND e.g. join, restriction, extension, intersection.

SQL's `INTERSECT` would be appropriate here e.g.

```
SELECT id_no
  FROM revenue_table
 WHERE revenue_type = 'Shipping' 
INTERSECT
SELECT id_no
  FROM revenue_table
 WHERE revenue_type = 'Reproduction' 
INTERSECT
SELECT id_no
  FROM revenue_table
 WHERE revenue_type = 'Tape';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with `INNER JOIN`:

```
select distinct r.id_no 
from revenue_table r
inner join revenue_table i1 on i1.id_no = r.id_no and i1.revenue_type = 'Shipping'
inner join revenue_table i2 on i2.id_no = r.id_no and i2.revenue_type = 'Reproduction'
inner join revenue_table i3 on i3.id_no = r.id_no and i3.revenue_type = 'Tape'
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent **only** because of the `DISTINCT` keyword being present.